# Node.js API - Works with Postman but not works in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create a `mean` application. as a sample, if I post the request through `postman` the data created at `mlab`.

in case if I post the same using `$http` way, it's not working getting the error as :

```
{
  "message": "Family validation failed",
  "name": "ValidationError",
  "errors": {
    "username": {
      "message": "Path `username` is required.",
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "properties": {
        "type": "required",
        "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
        "path": "username"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "username"
    },
    "password": {
      "message": "Path `password` is required.",
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "properties": {
        "type": "required",
        "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
        "path": "password"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "password"
    }
  }
}
```

and the node with mongoose :

```
.post(function( req, res ){

                var family = new Family();

                family.username = req.body.username,
                family.password = req.body.password,
                family.familyLeader = req.body.familyLeader,
                family.husband = req.body.husband,
                family.wife = req.body.wife,
                family.kids = req.body.kids;

                family.save(function( err, newFamily ) {

                    if( err ) {

                        if ( err.code == 11000) {
                            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'A user with that username already exists. '});
                        }
                        else {
                            return res.send( err );
                        }

                    }

                    res.json({ message: 'Family created!', newFamily: newFamily });

                });



            })
```

here is my angular code :

```
vm.createNewFamily = function() {

            $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : '/api/family',
                data    : vm.form,
                headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success( function ( data ) {

                console.log('retured!', data );

            })

        }
```

my full api.js ( node )

```
var Family = require('../models/model_family');

module.exports = function( app, express ) {

    var apiRoute = express.Router();

    apiRoute.use(function( req, res, next ) {

        console.log( 'some one using the app!' );
        next();

    })

    apiRoute.get('/', function( req, res ) {

        res.json({"namea" : "Arif"})

    });


    apiRoute.route('/family')

            .get(function( req, res ){

                res.send('family get processing');

            })

            .post(function( req, res ){

                var family = new Family();

                family.username = req.body.username,
                family.password = req.body.password,
                family.familyLeader = req.body.familyLeader,
                family.husband = req.body.husband,
                family.wife = req.body.wife,
                family.kids = req.body.kids;

                family.save(function( err, newFamily ) {

                    if( err ) {

                        if ( err.code == 11000) {
                            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'A user with that username already exists. '});
                        }
                        else {
                            return res.send( err );
                        }

                    }

                    res.json({ message: 'Family created!', newFamily: newFamily });

                });



            })


    return apiRoute;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure our req.body object have all data in it. From what I see your mongoose schema sends validation error... And what middleware you using on node side?

Comment: Can you post your server's main file?

Comment: @abdulbarik - i have added my full `node` side api.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

If you only have problems with username then check you angular data bindings. Im thinking you have typo somewhere like this

```
<input ng-model="useranme">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: here is my server.js, because already i am using `body-parser` : `var
 express  = require('express'),
 router  = express.Router(),
 config  = require('./server.config'),
 apiRoutes = require('./app/routes/api'),
 bodyParser  = require('body-parser'), // get body-parser
 morgan   = require('morgan'), // used to see requests
 mongoose = require('mongoose'),
 path  = require('path'), //sets path from where node runs
 app   = express();


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: Okay.. Does body-parser included before all routes?

Comment: But in post request, I tried to console the body properties, I am getting as undefined `console.log( 'family username', family.username ); undefined`

Comment: Okay.. In angular does your data bindings correct? does vm. form object collect all values from form? maybe some typo in bindings?

Comment: see here my cosole :

`console.log(' called ', req.body ); //getting all properties

    var family = new Family();

    family.username = req.body.username,
    family.password = req.body.password,
    family.familyLeader = req.body.familyLeader,
    family.husband = req.body.husband,
    family.wife = req.body.wife,
    family.kids = req.body.kids;

    console.log( 'family username', family.username ); //undefined? not getting`

Comment: Okay...But does all other properties have data in it like family.wife or family.husband...If they have data then look in data bindings. In your form you may have typo like usernaem or something like this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123093/discussion-between-mykola-borysyuk-and-user2024080).

Comment: my body request consoles something differently like this:
`called  { '{"username":"arif","password":"sadfdsa","familyLeader":"sadffsa","husband":"sadfsad","wife":"sadfsad","kids":2}': '' }`

Comment: may it require to convert as json string ?

Answer (score 0):

Put your this code above all the `routes` in your main server file

```
 ----------
  ----------
        var app=express();
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
          extended: true
        }));

  ---------
  ---------
```

Comment: put this line after ` var app = express(); `

Comment: see my api file here : http://plnkr.co/edit/OsaBfq30XoRFTKW5lm4q?p=preview